# Fetching Geo Data using Volley giving Error 403

Tags: android, google-maps, android-volley

This is basically my end [url](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=true&latlng=28.6338751,77.3630051&language=en) which is giving me correct address component in the browser. But when I am using volley to fetch the same data I am getting error 403.

```
final StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(
                "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=true&latlng=");
        url.append(latitude);
        url.append(',');
        url.append(longitude);
        url.append("&language=");
        url.append(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());

        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")


    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url.toString(),
                new Response.Listener() {      

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Object arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println();
                try {

                    String address = (new JSONObject(arg0.toString())).getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getString("formatted_address");
                    location.setText(address);  
                    ProjectUtil.crossfade(layout, progress);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                System.out.println();
            }
        });

        queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

With the API request in the REST client gives the response that is expected out of it. In these cases it is always the network that cause trouble, Please check to see the network you are using for your android app to make connection is a shared network? And/or one that uses a proxy for outgoing 
requests? Looks like someone on the same network is 
downloading stuff from Google and causing blocks.

One reason may be also because you are exceeding the API request limit. For more details read about the [quota request](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#geocoder_limit).

For more information, I would like to see the logcat!!